# Определение определённой кнопки в jquery

Tags: html, css, jquery

У меня есть 4 разных div с одинаковым названия класса и 4 кнопки в них. По имени класса я могу обратиться чтобы считать действие. Но так как у меня одинаковые названия классов, то немного не корректно работает. Как определить именно определённой кнопки нажатие? И нужно изменить текст не через jquery. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass("shadow");
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.btn:active > .hidden {
  display:inline-block
}

.btn:active > .showed {
  display:none
}

.shadow {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">
  <span class="showed">showed</span>
  <span class="hidden">hidden</span>
</button>

<button class="toggle">
  toggle
</button>
```

Comment: Я так обрабатываю:$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("div").toggleClass("shadow");

Comment: $('button').on('click', function(event) { 
 $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass("shadow")
})

Comment: А как название кнопки можно поменять, не в jquery?

Comment: $('button').on('click', function(event) { 
 $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass("shadow");
  $(event.currentTarget).text("новый текст")
})

Comment: Надо менять не здесь, а в css

Comment: не понял, что значит "менять название кнопки в css"? Если нужен нативный JS без jquery, то так: event.currentTarget.textContent="Новый текст"

Comment: Не используя js

Comment: При нажатии один текст, при отжатии другой

Comment: затрудняюсь ответить. Через CSS можно изменить стиль текста (цвет, шрифт, фон и т.п.), что касается самого текста, то его, насколько мне известно, напрямую через CSS изменить нельзя. Как вариант, можно сделать внутри кнопки два строчных блока с содержимым, в CSS сделать классы, и через псевдоклассы (hover, active и т.п.) задавать когда отображать какой из блоков. В исходном ответе закреплю пример. 2 мин.

Comment: @xydope `input type="checkbox", type="radio"`, элемент `label` и селектор `:checked`- в хитрых комбинациях можно делать всякие функциональные штуки. Другое дело, что они усложняют и ограничивают разметку и зачастую легче все сделать на JS)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME это понятно, я-то отталкивался от условий задачи. Использовать button и jquery :)