# Изменить текст кнопки

Tags: html, css, jquery

Всем привет. Как можно изменить название кнопки(2 названия в активном состоянии и не активном), не задавая названия кнопок напрямую?

Comment: покажите кнопку хотя бы - это инпут, батон, див?

Comment: Я использую батон в списке

Comment: гут. тепер объясните, пазязя, что значит активное и не активное состояние в вашем случае?  и как эти события наступают?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определение определённой кнопки в jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071179/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но мне показалось по вопросу, что вам нужно немного другое. А именно `checkbox`, у которого активный/неактивный состояния как раз есть.

```css
input[type='checkbox']{display:none}
.box span{width:75px;height:30px;border:1px solid;border-radius:4px;display:block;cursor:pointer}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + span{background-color:green}
input[type='checkbox'] + span:after{content:'inactive';padding:5px;display:block;margin:0 auto;text-align:center}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + span:after{content:'active';color:white}
```

```html
<label class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" />
  <span></span>
</label>
```

**upd:**

В случае с `button` это нереализуемо без `js` по причине того, что состояние `active` у `button` наступает тода, когда на кнопку нажали и заканчивается, когда её отпустили.

Comment: Изящное решение. В принципе тоже самое можно сделать с `button`, только с разными стилями и через переключение их в js.

Answer (score 5):

Например с помощью css:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  } else {
    $this.removeClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn .a {
  display: none;
}

.btn .dis {
  display: block;
}

.btn.active .a {
  display: block;
}

.btn.active .dis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="btn"><span class="dis">disactive</span><span class="a">active</span></a>
```

Comment: Так в том и вопрос напрямую нельзя давать текст в jquery

Comment: @Александр, а в чем проблема? Опишите свою проблему подробнее и желательно с примером кода

Comment: Работать должно как вы описали правильно, но надо чтобы текст кнопок задавался не в js

Comment: @Александр, обновила, стилями управляем отображением необходимого текста

Comment: @HamSter ☝❤ )))

Answer (score 3):

Можно примерно так:

```css
button.active:before {
  content: 'click me'
}

button:not(.active):after {
  content: 'click again'
}
```

```html
<button onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')"></button>
```